# OpenGL ES 1.1/2.0 shaders to compare images on Android

Tags: java, android, c, opengl-es, shader

i'm developing a software that compare images and i need to do it in a fast way! Actually i compare them using plain c but it's too slow.

I want to compare them using shaders and a couple of gl surfaces (textures), using c and not java, but this doesn't change the situation so much, and get back a list of changed parts, but i really don't know where to start.

Basically i want to use something like SIMD neon instruction to compare pixel colors to check for changes (well, i need to check only the first pixel fragment color, ex. only red ... these are photos so is unrealistic that it doesn't change) but instead to use neon instructions i want to use pixel shaders to do the comparison and get the list of changed part back

More, if it's possible, i want to use parallel comparison on the same image splitting it in blocks :)

Someone can give an hit?

note: i know that i can't output back a list of stuff, but, well, use a third texture as output is good anyway for me (if i put on the texture 2 ushorts that indicates x and y i'm ok and with an uint on the end of the texture that report the number of changed pixels)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL ES 1.1 doesn't have shaders, and the best route I can think of for what you want to do ends with a 50% reduction in colour precision. Issues are:

1. without extensions there's additive blending, but not subtractive. No problem, just upload the second of your textures with all colour values inverted.
2. OpenGL clamps output colours to the range [0, 1] and without extensions you're limited to one byte per channel. So you'd need to upload textures with 7bit colour channels to ensure you got the correct results within the 8bits coming back.

Shaders would allow a slightly circuitous route around that, because you can add or subtract or do whatever you want, and can split up the results. If you're sending two three channel 24bit images in to get a four channel 32bit image out, obviously there's enough space to fit in 9 bits per source channel, even though you're going to have to divide the data oddly and reconstruct it later.

In practice you're going to pay quite a lot for uploading and downloading images from the GPU, so NEON might be a better choice not just to avoid packing peculiarities. Assuming the Android kit supplies the same compiler intrinsics as the iPhone kit (likely, since they'll both include GCC), [this page](http://hilbert-space.de/?p=22) has a bit of an introduction showing how to convert an image to greyscale. So it's not exactly what you're looking for, but it's image processing in C using NEON so it should be a good start.

In both cases you're likely to end up with an image of the differences, rather than a simple count and list. A count is a concurrent operation, whatever way you think about it, so isn't 
really something you'd do in GL or via NEON. You'd need to inspect the final image to work it out.

Comment: i agree that up/downloading might result in no improvement at all. best try is neon or packing 4 greyscale pixels in 1 register(variable).